# error object doesn't contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have a .NET Core project that I want to run but I get the error

> error object doesn't contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments

This is my code:

```
 public class OrderDetailsContext
    {
        public OrderDetailsContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDetailsContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        //defining table
        public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

what should I do?

Comment: `public class OrderDetailsContext : DbContext` you do not inherit from DbContext!

Answer (score 5):

You did not inherit from DbContext.

```
 public class OrderDetailsContext : DbContext
    {
        public OrderDetailsContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDetailsContext> options) : base(options)
        { }

        //defining table
        public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your class should **inheritance** from **DbContext** class:

```
public class OrderDetailsContext: DbContext
        {
            public OrderDetailsContext(DbContextOptions<OrderDetailsContext> options) : base(options)
            { 
            }

            // defining table
            public DbSet<OrderDetails> OrderDetails { get; set; }
        }
```

[Help Link 1](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/efcore/entity-framework-core-dbcontext.aspx)

[Help Link 2](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/entityframework6/dbcontext.aspx)